# Styling the sphinx theme search page

Tags: python-sphinx

Okay so I went ahead and styled the sphinx theme, but the styles aren't being applied to the search results page.

```
{# layout.html #}
{# Import the theme's layout. #} 
{% extends "!page.html" %}

{% set css_files = css_files + ['_static/theme.css'] %} {% set script_files = script_files + ['_static/myscript.js'] %}
```

What can I do to get the same styles working on the search results page?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change

`{% extends "!page.html" %}`

to

`{% extends "!layout.html" %}`

it should work.